# wpf TabControl, possible to organize each tab in a different class?

Tags: c#, wpf

Basically on my mainWindow Class it's getting crowded. My main question would be how to add the events on another class ?

So I tried adding a tabControl ... and wondering if each tabs control can be in a separate xaml and/or class.

an example would be much appreciated ;P Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<Window .......  xmlns:uControl="clr-namespace:YOURPROJECT" >


<TabItem>
    <uControl:UserControl1/>
</TabItem>
```

Two links that should help:

- [C# Corner: UserControl in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpfusercontrol06292008215701pm/wpfusercontrol.aspx)
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590031/tabitem-in-a-separate-xaml)

..and for your next problem: [call-a-parent-method-from-UserControl](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/blogs/Call-a-parent-method-from-UserControl-using-WPF.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Each TabItem has a content property that can be set to whatever you want. The easiest way to seperate this out, is to put each section into a UserControl, and then just set your TabItems to those controls.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <my:UserControl1 />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <my:UserControl2 />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Where **"my"** has been mapped to some namespace in your solution that contains your UserControls.