# What is the best way to share data between a WPF window and its User Controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

WPF can be infuriating sometimes.

I have a fairly simple application that consists of a single main window that contains a tab control and several tabs.  I did not like the idea of having the code for all tabs in the same file, so I used the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590031/tabitem-in-a-separate-xaml) to break out each tab into a separate user control.

Inside my main window I have an instance of an object that contains application settings, and some other application-wide data.  Several of my tabs require access to this data for data binding purposes.  I have not been able to find a good way to accomplish this.

First I tried to access the parent window in the controls Loaded event and get a reference to the property in the main window that exposed the settings object, as shown in the code below.  This kind of works, except the Loaded event is fired every time the tab gains focus.  Also, this event occurs late in the control life cycle so I am not able to bind to any of the properties in this object in the user controls XAML.

```
private void MyUserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ApplicationSettings = ((MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this)).ApplicationSettings;
}
```

Then I experimented with passing the data into the user controls constructor, but there is no way to do that in XAML.

Given that these are application-wide settings I could make the ApplicationSettings class singleton and reference it everywhere, but I would prefer not to do that for unit testing purposes.

So how does one accomplish something like this?  Is my approach just fundamentally flawed?  In my mind all of these UI elements are part of the same window and therefore should be able to access data from the main window, but the object model does not appear to allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the settings object into a static property in a wrapper class (`SettingsHolder` in this example and reference it application wide via

in XAML:

```
{Binding SettingName, Source={x:Static local:SettingsHolder.Settings}}
```

with `local` being the namespace your `SettingsHolder` class is in.

in Code:

```
var x = SettingsHolder.Settings.SettingName;
SettingsHolder.Settings.SettingName = x;
```

Comment: I think this is the route that I'm going to take.  Like I said in the original post, I want singleton behavior without the actual singleton, and this gives me that.  Actually, I will probably make the class singleton, but leave the constructor public for testing purposes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the declaration of your user control you could just set the data context to the instance of the object that contains all the things you need to bind to!

`<someNamespace:EricsUserControl DataContext="{Binding InstanceOfBindingObject}"/>`

Then you can access the properties of that objects' instance within the user control as you normally would.

Comment: This is really good to know, and I might use this for some other things, but I would like to leave the option open to access the settings in code as well.

Comment: @EricTheRed perfectly sensible, but just a heads up, you can access the DataContext for a user control within the code as well. So if you bound to the instance object as above and then within the code-behind file did some little `var myInstance = (BindingObjectClass) this.DataContext` you could be able to access that object from the myInstance variable! Hope that helps sometime in the future!

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use a `Frame` in the `Tab` and place a `Page` in the `Frame`. (but I think the same can apply with a User Control).  The constructor only fires when the Page is created and you can control when the page is created and you can pass information in the constructor.  A Page has more lifecycle events to tie into.   I also use the Loaded event for building UI (it just fires once).   If you bind the Page in XAML it will fire when you start the app and you cannot pass information.   This is creating a page and showing it in a dialog but that page could be bound to a frame.

```
        NavigationWindow winSearchXML;
        using (new WaitCursor())
        {
            winSearchXML = new NavigationWindow();
            winSearchXML.Content = new PageSearchResultsXML(GabeLib.GetSearchXML(GabeLib.enumXMLtype.Flat));
        }
        winSearchXML.ShowDialog();
```

I need to be honest that some times I get a life cycle on a page that I just don't understand.  So take this with a grain of salt.   But the point is you have the contructor and loaded events that might give you what you need.

Comment: That's clever!  I never thought of doing something like that.  I think for what I'm working on however this is a little overkill.  Thanks for the idea though.