# How do i create a wrapper class for setting to use in WPF?

Tags: wpf, tabs

I need to create a wrapper class to retain the setting for a WPF application as Nuffin said here: [What is the best way to share data between a WPF window and its User Controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771872/what-is-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-a-wpf-window-and-its-user-controls) . I have several tabs that require some specific settings (also I need to update a setting from a tab and be updated for all tabs). How do I share the setting for all tabs and how do I access the setting from MainWindow and from a tab. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *setting*? Do you mean `Styles` or are you talking of let's call it application settings like `ConnectionStrings` a.s.o.?

Comment: No, i use a sensor for my project and i need to change sensor states in main window based on the buttons from tab. Those states i need to be visible in tabs(to change theirs values) and be the same with the states from main window.

Comment: In the MainWindow i have the manager for the sensor and i can't put that manager elsewhere becase i show data from him in MainWindow. MainWindow also contain a TabControl with different tabs: InteractionManager, Setting, Info. For example in interaction manager i have a record button and i need when that button is press to change the state of boolean value isRecording to true. isRecording is a data member from MainWindow. Thanks!