# How do I add TabItems into the TabControl of a custom UserControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, tabcontrol, tabitem

Okay, so I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590031/tabitem-in-a-separate-xaml) and it shows how to add a custom `TabItem` into a `TabControl` in the current XAML, but what about if I want to add `TabItems` into a custom `TabControl` in XAML?

So I created my custom `TabControl` `UserControl`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="myLibrary.MyTabControl">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>>
    </DockPanel>
    <TabControl x:Name=tc">
        <TabControl.LayoutTransform>
            <!-- Allows to zoom the control's content using the slider -->
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" 
                CenterY="0"
                ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
                ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSlider,Path=Value}"/>
        </TabControl.LayoutTransform>
    </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

Then, I want to add static `TabItems` into the `MyUserControl` `UserControl`, like below

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyLibrary.Forms.MyTabForm"
    xmlns:Utilities="clr-namespace:myLibrary;assembly=myLibrary">
<Utilities:MyTabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <tc>
        <tc.Items>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 0"/>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 1"/>
        </tc.Items>
    </tc>
</Utilities:MyTabControl>
</UserControl>
```

Instead of using the default WPF `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl1" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"  DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 0 (0)" Name="tabItem0">
        <Grid Name="tabItem0Grid" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1 (0)" Name="tabItem1">
        <Grid Name="tabItem1Grid" />
    </TabItem>
```

Comment: can't you do tc.TabItem instead of tc.Items?

Comment: @sexta13 I can't get it to recognize the `tc` part. I added `x:FieldModifier="public"`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a `DependencyProperty` to your `UserControl` that would enable users to `Bind` the items to the `TabControl.Items` property in the control:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.
    Register("Items", typeof(ItemCollection), typeof(MyTabControl));

public ItemCollection Items
{
    get { return (ItemCollection)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

Then you could `Bind` to this property inside your control using a `RelativeSource Binding` like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myLibrary.MyTabControl">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>>
    </DockPanel>
    <TabControl x:Name=tc" Items="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType={x:Type YourXmlNamespace:MyTabControl}}}">
        <TabControl.LayoutTransform>
            <!-- Allows to zoom the control's content using the slider -->
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" 
                CenterY="0"
                ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
                ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSlider,Path=Value}"/>
        </TabControl.LayoutTransform>
    </TabControl>
</UserControl>
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
<Utilities:MyTabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Items="{Binding SomeItemCollection}" />
```

Comment: What if I didn't want to use binding? Would it be better for me to create my class that inherited from `TabControl`? I have a `Slider` for zoom that I want to add below the `TabContent`. I think that would require me to change the TabControl Template though.

Comment: I haven't tried that personally, but it certainly makes sense to me. If you replace `UserControl` with `TabControl` in your control, then I would imagine that you could do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add dependency property type of IEnumerable to your `User Control` (`UserControlItemsSource` for example)
2. Bind property `ItemsSource` of your tab control to this dependency property ( `ItemsSource="{Binding UserControlItemsSource,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"`)
3. When you use your User Control - bind dependency property of your User Control (`UserControlItemsSource`).