# Design view + user control/tabitem shows up as empty button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

So I wanted to separate TabItems for a TabControl into different files. I found a recommendation to Create user contraols for each tab and then replace UserControl with TabItem. That worked and I was able to reference the standalone TabItem in my TabControl and the tab is viewable inside of the running application. The only problem is that the TabItem is no longer able to be viewed in Design view. I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that since it is a standalone TabItem that is not wrapped inside of a tabcontrol.

The following link is the reference I used: [TabItem in a separate XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590031/tabitem-in-a-separate-xaml)

Comment: Could you provide some code examples of what you currently have regarding the custom `TabItem`s

Comment: @MicheldeNijs - I posted my solution with the wrong and right code.

Answer (score 0):

NVM. I figured it out. It was a matter of keeping it as a user control and including it inside of the TabItem rather than renaming UserControl to TabItem and including that inside of the TabControll.

**WRONG:**

```
<TabControl>
    <myTabItems:Tab1 />
    <myTabItems:Tab2 />
    ...
    <myTabItems:Tabn />
</TabControl>
```

The TabItem Control (**WRONG**)

```
<TabItem x:Class="MyProject.My_Tabs.Tab1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

**RIGHT:**

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <myTabItems:Tab1 />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <myTabItems:Tab2 />
    </TabItem>
    ...
    <TabItem>
        <myTabItems:Tabn />
    </TabItem>    
</TabControl>
```

The TabItem Control (**RIGHT**)

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.My_Tabs.Tab1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```