# Need help to understand how to connect two xaml files

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabs

I need to use a tabItem in a different xaml file and I do not understand how to do it.

I have visited Tonny Bores answer here: [TabItem in a separate XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590031/tabitem-in-a-separate-xaml)

But I do not understand where does the tabData come from.

```
<TabItem x:Class="Hysolate.DisplayTab"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <TabItem.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TStyle"
               TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </TabItem.Resources>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TStyle}"  Text="Tab No. 2"></TextBlock>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Tab Data" />
    </Grid>
</TabItem>

<!-- And I want to use it here (different xaml file):

    <TabControl>
        <tabdata:DisplayTab></tabdata:DisplayTab>
    </TabControl>

-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabdata` is your UserControl(xaml file A), you need to specify this in your xml file(xaml file B) header like following:

```xml
<Window ... 
    xmlns:tabdata="clr-namespace:AssemblyName"//replace AssemblyName to your user control name
    ...
/>
```

Then you can use it in xaml code like what you did

```xml
    <tabdata:YourUserControl></tabdata:YouUserControl>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks For your response. And how do I actually use the tabdata? After the adding the line you wrote, how to make the xaml file use it?

Comment: I modify it in the answer